# Broadcast Or AIDL, which is better to communicate between apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, aidl

I have been using BROADCAST to send msgs from one app to another app in Android, now I came to know whe can do the same using AIDL. Which way is better.?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

AIDL and Broadcast both can be use for communication. Complexity point of view, AIDL is complex compare to Broadcast.
If you want to pass any sensitive information then AIDL is preferable because in AIDL client and service app both have common interface and communication happens where as in case of Broadcast it might possible some other app listen to your broadcast.